# How do I install a userscript?

Tags: greasemonkey, browser, userscripts

What are the steps to install a userscript for any of the major browsers? This question is for the benefit of those trying to get the minimal theme working. One browser per answer please.

Comment: Related: [How to install a private user script in Chrome 21+?](https://superuser.com/q/450893/259382)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Detailed instructions are available on the Stack Apps Site](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)

> #### How to install user scripts in Chrome
>
> There are two methods for installing UserScripts in Chrome. The first
>   is to install the
>   [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)
>   extension, which makes installation simple and easy. The second is to
>   follow these instructions below:
>
> > **Note:** As of Chrome 35 (late May 2014), downloaded user scripts cannot be installed using the second method. Please use the
> >     [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)
> >     extension.
>
> 1. Click on the link to the `.user.js` file found in the post
> 2. Look for the confirmation at the bottom of your browser and click **`Continue`**.
>
>    [image: Are you sure you want to continue?]
> 3. Chrome will warn you that you can't install the script. [image: Chrome warns: Extensions, apps and user scripts can only be added from the Chrome Web store.]
>    Because Google has disabled the direct
>      installation of extensions that are not downloaded from their Web
>      Store, you'll have to perform a few extra steps before you can use the
>      script.
> 4. The script should have appeared in your downloads bar.
> 5. If the file name is modified to `<filename>.user (<number>).js`, rename the file so it ends with `.user.js`. **Note:** If file
>      extensions are not displayed on your system, the name has to end with
>      `.user`.
> 6. Open the extensions manager. Go to **Menu** button > **Tools** > **Extensions** to open the extensions manager[image: the extension manager]
> 7. Drag drop the file from the downloads bar to the extensions page. If you had renamed it, drag-drop it from your file manager.
> 8. Release the mouse if the text "Drop to install" appears.
> 9. A dialog appears. Click **`Add`** to finish the installation. [image: Confirm New Extension - click "Add" to install the script]
> 10. The script should now be installed. Refresh all tabs affected by the script to start using it.
>
> ---
>
> #### How to install user scripts in Firefox
>
> 1. Install the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) add-on for Firefox if you haven't done so already
> 2. Click on the link to the `.user.js` file found in the post.
> 3. A Greasemonkey Installation dialog will appear. Review the sites on which this script will work on, view the source of the script if so
>      desired and confirm that you wish to install the script
>
>    [image: Greasemonkey Installation dialog]
> 4. The script should now be installed. Refresh all tabs affected by the script to start using it.
>
> #### How to install user scripts in Safari
>
> GreaseKit (The hack approach, for Safari 4 and earlier)
>
> 1. [Download and Install SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) – (From the SIMBL website), SIMBL, pronounced like “symbol” or “cymbal” enables hacks. In other words,
>      you can “patch” Mac applications to add functionality to them.
> 2. Next, [download GreaseKit](http://8-p.info/greasekit/). To install it, drag the `GreaseKit.bundle` file to `~/Library/Application
>      Support/SIMBL/Plugins`. If you don’t have a `SIMBL/Plugins/` folder,
>      just create it, then drop `GreaseKit.bundle` into it.
> 3. Restart Safari, and you will see a new entry in the menu bar for “GreaseKit”.
> 4. Click on the link to the `.user.js` file found in the post to install the userscript.
> 5. The script should now be installed. Refresh all tabs affected by the script to start using it.
>
>    <sup>from http://mosheberman.com/wordpress/?p=284</sup>
>
> NinjaKit (a Safari 5 extension)
>
> 1. Go to the [NinjaKit homepage](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/os0x/20100612/1276330696). The page is
>      in Japanese, but don't worry—the install link is in English.
> 2. Click on the "NinjaKit for Safari" link.
> 3. If you are prompted to open or save the file, select open. If the file automatically downloads, find the downloaded file
>      (`NinjaKit.safariextz`) and double-click it.
> 4. When Safari pops up a message confirming you want to install NinkaKit, click install.
>
> #### How to install user scripts in Opera 15 and newer versions
>
> Install [the TamperMonkey extension](http://tampermonkey.net/), which
>   makes installation simple and easy.
>
> #### How to install user scripts in Opera 12 and older versions
>
> 1. Create a folder for userscripts.  (eg, `C:\Program Files\Opera Browser\Userscripts\` - it does *not* need to be within the Program
>      Files folder, anywhere is fine.)
> 2. Within Opera, go to **`Tools`** > **`Preferences`**.
> 3. Click the **`Advanced`** tab.
> 4. Click **`Content`** in the choices on the left.
> 5. Click **`JavaScript options`**.
> 6. For the "User JavaScript files", click **`Choose`**.
> 7. Select the userscripts folder created in step 1. and click **`OK`**.
> 8. Click on the link to the `.user.js` file and save it to the userscripts folder created in step 1.
> 9. Refresh the tab(s) affected by the script to start using it.
>
>    <sup>from
>      http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/3986/set-up-user-scripts-in-opera-browser/</sup>
>
> #### Development resources
>
> - [UserScripts](http://userscripts.org:8080/) - a site to host Greasemonkey scripts.
> - [How to use jQuery in your scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246901/include-jquery-inside-greasemonkey-script-under-google-chrome/5047789#5047789)

Comment: What content type should a web server use in to make the Safari version of the instructions work properly? It looks like just naming the file .user.js is not enough.

Comment: I would guess `application/javascript` but I am not positive... Sounds like a good question for you to post @dpk!

Comment: In Chrome 21+ it’s not that easy anymore, sadly :( See here: [How to install a private user script in Chrome 21+?](https://superuser.com/q/450893/3218)

Comment: This answer is outdated. In Opera 15+ you’ll need to [install Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) to enable and manage user scripts.