# Install user scripts on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

I created a JavaScript file, and named it `test.user.js`. I tried double clicking it, dragging & dropping it into Chrome and opening it with Chrome, but it won't install.

I've already installed the dev version of Chrome, because it's stated somewhere that it's needed, but I can't get it to work. Then, I tried searching for a Chrome Greasemonkey addon, just to see that it was no further developed on, because Chrome has built-in support.

Could someboy tell me what I have to do in order to get user scripts working on Chrome v21?

Comment: Hmm, when I wrote my first Chrome user-script, the key to getting it to work was to make sure that the filename ended with `.user.js` instead of just `.js`, but you've already tried that. What exactly happens when you drag it to Chrome? Does it prompt you to save the file?

Comment: It does really nothing. It doesn't download or give any prompt. It's just like if I didn't actually do anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install a userscript?](http://superuser.com/questions/252046/how-do-i-install-a-userscript)

Comment: Check the downloads page; is it listed in there?

Comment: @Synetech Nope, nothing there. There's literally no reaction.

Comment: Do you get a prompt when downloading other files? Check you download settings in the options. Make sure that the download folder points to a valid location (i.e., not a folder that you have since deleted). Try toggling the *ask for location* option.

Comment: It could be a bug with the Dev version. Try making a local HTML file with a link to the userscript.

Comment: I've always just opened the `*.user.js` file and it prompted me to install it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have "New Downloads UI" enabled in `chrome://flags/`. If so, disable it & relaunch it.

This is [known to prevent user scripts](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108623) from being downloaded.

Comment: Wow, indeed, I have it enabled. I'll try it out as soon as I get to. Thanks.

Comment: Tried it, and it works now. Thanks alot for this tip, I would never have tought about something like that.

Comment: @Ahatius you're welcome - I'd run into the same (the linked bug report was filed by me). Glad you're able to get it running!

Answer (score 2):

## April 2020 Answer

In Chrome 81+, go to chrome://extensions, click to enable Developer Mode on the top right corner, then drag and drop to install your .user.js script.

Answer (score 1):

> ... I tried searching for a Chrome Greasemonkey addon, just to see that it was no further developed on, because Chrome has built-in support.

**[Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/)** is a Greasemonkey equivalent for Chrome and is currently being actively developed.

> **Tampermonkey** is a free browser extension and the most popular userscript manager for Blink-based Browsers like Chrome and Opera Next. Even though Google Chrome does have native support for Userscripts, Tampermonkey can give you much more convenience in managing your Userscripts. It provides features like automatic update checks, a overview what scripts are running at a tab and there is a good chance that scripts that are incompatible to Google Chrome run with Tampermonkey.
>
> Tampermonkey is available for Google Chrome, Opera, Chromium and a lot of their derivates like CoolNovo and Rockmelt.