# How to install a private user script in Chrome 21+?

Tags: google-chrome, userscripts

In Chrome 20 and older versions, you could simply open any `.user.js` file in Chrome and it would prompt you to install the user script.

However, in Chrome 21 and up, it downloads the file instead, and displays a warning at the top saying “Extensions, apps, and user scripts can only be added from the Chrome Web Store”.

[image: Screenshot]

The “Learn More” link points to http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2664769, but that page doesn’t say anything about user scripts, only about extensions in `.crx` format, apps, and themes.

This part sounded interesting:

> **Enterprise Administrators:** You can specify URLs that are allowed to install extensions, apps, and themes directly through [the `ExtensionInstallSources` policy](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources).

So, I ran the following commands, then restarted Chrome and Chrome Canary:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallSources -array "https://gist.github.com/*"
defaults write com.google.Chrome.canary ExtensionInstallSources -array "https://gist.github.com/*"
```

Sadly, these settings only seem to affect extensions, apps, and themes (as it says in the text), not user scripts. (I’ve [filed a bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138054) asking to make this setting affect user scripts as well.)

Any ideas on how to install a private user script (that I don’t want to add to the Chrome Web Store) in Chrome 21+?

Comment: Have you tried enabling developer mode in Settings -> Extensions? Not sure if its gonna work but you can give it a try.

Comment: @Rhyuk Thanks for the suggestion. I had developer mode enabled, though — doesn’t seem to make a difference.

Comment: Related: [How do I install a userscript?](https://superuser.com/q/252046)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem was that `gist.github.com`’s raw URLs redirect to a different domain. So, we have to use these commands instead:

```
# Allow installing user scripts via GitHub or Userscripts.org
defaults write com.google.Chrome ExtensionInstallSources -array "https://*.github.com/*" "http://userscripts.org/*"
defaults write com.google.Chrome.canary ExtensionInstallSources -array "https://*.github.com/*" "http://userscripts.org/*"
```

This works!

---

Anyway, this seems to be a workaround (thanks to [Paul Horn](https://twitter.com/knutwalker/status/225923497623433216) for the hint):

1. Download the user script.
2. Open `chrome://chrome/extensions/`.
3. Drag and drop the user script file on the page you opened in step 2.

Comment: This seems better than having to edit the command used to open Chromium. Thanks!

Comment: @btleffler Except that you'll have to jump through that hoop every time, rather than making the change once.

Comment: NB. When drag and dropping, you need to drop the file exactly onto the message. Anywhere else on the page won't work.

Comment: is the drag and drop way of adding extensions still working? It does not seem like that on Chrome 24 on OSX.

Comment: It bears mentioning that github allows the hosting of user-generated content on <username>.github.com (via "Github Pages" - http://pages.github.com).

Just a heads up for anyone for whom this would be a security concern.

Comment: Where do you enter the commands?

Comment: @Sam In your terminal.

Comment: Drag&Drop opens the script in chrome, it doesn't install anything. Is there a normal way to install script?

Comment: @ŁukaszLech You need to drag it to `chrome://chrome/extensions/`, not just to the Chrome window.

Answer (score 36):

Start Chrome with [the `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install` switch](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#enable-easy-off-store-extension-install).

To use a command line switch ([from Chromium.org](http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags)):

On Windows:

- Right click on your "Chrome" icon.
- Choose properties
- At the end of your target line, place these parameters:
  `--enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`
- It should look like: `chrome.exe --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`

On OS X:

- `/Applications/Chromium.app/Contents/MacOS/Chromium --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`
- For Google Chrome you'll need to escape spaces like so: 
  `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`

On Linux:

- `chromium-browser --enable-easy-off-store-extension-install`

Comment: You have to quit chrome completely, not just open a new window from the icon. (this is rubbish of Google btw)

Comment: Yep, this is encroaching on "evil" territory IMO.

Comment: This worked... :) The answer of @MathiasBynens didn't work on MacOS/Chrome25

Comment: I have a problem on windows http://dl2.joxi.net/drive/0005/3037/338909/141218/3935c61eb8.jpg

Comment: Pretty sure this stopped working sometime after August, 2014. Doesn't seem to work now at all.

Answer (score 10):

Well, this took a couple hours of my life to figure out.  I guess Google engineers think that we only deserve to install untrusted extensions if we can figure out how to do tricks and jump through their hoops.

The instructions in [Mathias's answer](https://superuser.com/a/450903/9599) look to be spot-on for Mac OS X, but I use Linux.  Here's what I did on Linux to enable easier (pre-Chrome-21-style) install of **all** third-party extensions, apps, and user scripts **from any website**:

1. Create the policies directory (if it doesn't already exist):

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /etc/opt/chrome/policies/recommended/
   ```
2. Create the policy file:

   ```
   cd /etc/opt/chrome/policies/recommended/

   sudo tee easy_install_extensions.json <<EOF
   {
       "ExtensionInstallSources": ["<all_urls>"]
   }
   EOF
   ```
3. Restart Chrome.  Completely exit the program via `menu -> Exit`; don't just close your current window.

---

**Sources:**

- [This page](http://www.howtogeek.com/120743/how-to-install-extensions-from-outside-the-chrome-web-store/) recommends drag and drop, which didn't work for me
- [Documentation for the relevant policy setting](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallSources)
- [Rules for URL match patterns](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)
- [How to set Chromium policies on Linux](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start)

**Notes:**

- `<all_urls>` (used above) is a special pattern according to the [URL match docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).  Good to know about.
- According to the [Linux policy docs](http://www.chromium.org/administrators/linux-quick-start), the directories `/etc/opt/chrome/policies/{managed,recommended}/` contain JSON policy files.  If entries conflict, `managed` overrides `recommended`.

Comment: I didn’t know about `<all_urls>` — very useful. Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed to work in Fedora 18. Awesome post, extremely helpful!

Comment: Awesome! Drag and drop didn't work before, and now it works!