# How to customise/choose your own colors in Google Keep?

Tags: google-chrome, colors, google-chrome-extensions, web-application, google-keep

Is there a way to customise the predefined background colors in Google Keep?

*The context of this question is Google Keep (https://keep.google.com) in Chrome, together with the Category Tabs for Google Keep Chrome extension. Both with and without the extension, the question is valid.*

The related help article from Google Keep Help Center, [Label, color, or pin notes](https://support.google.com/keep/answer/6191044?hl=en) doesn't provide instructions to customize colors, it limit to say "Select the color".

---

I find some of the colors repulsive or aggressive or simply poorly chosen because of the low contrast difference between background and foreground text note color. I know you can choose fancy elephant background images from their again predefined set, but I do not want background images to compensate for this defect.

All I want is to have the freedom to choose the background color of a category.
So far I have not been able to "hack" this.

[image: Google Keep note - Red]

Using the cool Category Tabs Extension for Chrome, I can group notes by the same color. However when I click on the round colors, instead of geting a popup box where you chose my own desired color, the mouse click toggles the adjecent checkboxes on the left.

I want to change the colors to my own taste and my own choosing. What can be done to achieve this in Google Keep?

---

[image: Category Setup UI of Category Tabs for Google Keep Chrome extension]

Comment: Is this question about using `https://keep.google.com`(Google Keep in a web browser) or about using installable app / browser extension? Why the [tag:google-chrome-extensions] and [tag:desktop-customization] tag are included in this question? Please bear in mind that tags should be included based on what is being asked not just becuase something what was mentioned to provide a example of the expected result / behavior.

Comment: Both/together in tandem! Like two gears working together not this gear or that gear. Bear in mind that most seasoned users using Google Keep, use it together with the Keep Category Tabs for Google Keep extension. Thanks to your comment I have updated/clarified the question! Back on topic, Do you have an answer to this question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. [tag:desktop-customization] is for questions about customizing the operative system's desktop, not for for quesitons about using the desktop version of a web app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tl;Dr: Learn about [userscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript). This site has **[userscripts](/questions/tagged/userscripts)**, [html](/questions/tagged/html),[css](/questions/tagged/css),[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript),[styles](/questions/tagged/styles) among other related tags..

---

From the question

> All I want is to have the freedom to choose the background color of a category.
> So far I have not been able to "hack" this.

This question looks more as a *feedback* that you should send directly to Google than a "question" for Super User or any Stack Exchange site as there is no site for customer service like questions.

To send you feedback to Google, on https://keep.google.com, click the gear (Settings) button them Send Feedback.

[image: Send Feedback]

Anyway to "hack this" you might use userscript / usertyle to make Chrome replace the ugly colors for those that you like.

Try searching for already existing userstyls, i.e.

- `userstyle "google keep" notes custom color` the first result returned to me by Google Search was

> Google keep - Note colors - Userstyles.org
> `https://userstyles.org › styles › google-keep-note-colors`
> Sep 19, 2019 — This style let you pick custom colors for you notes on Google Keep. Show CSS Code. Notes from latest update: Install style as userscript.

That points to https://userstyles.org/styles/175464/google-keep-note-colors

Related

- [Understanding CSS for user styling in a browser](https://superuser.com/q/234952/152004)
- [How do I install a userscript?](https://superuser.com/q/252046/152004)